# Android Studio 3.0 toast. Logical Error?

Tags: android

Hello a beginner here and starting to learn android.
I was watching a android tutorial on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7HPQ6DVvug&index=9&list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E

But when I try to do it on my Android Studio 3.0
and click the button there's no toast is happening?

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7efH.jpg)

let me know what other source you need from me to answer my questions. Thank you.

Comment: Please copy your code inside the question without using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `addListenerOnCall` method but you miss a call to it, in fact, hovering method name with your mouse, will give you a warning about the method not being used.

You might want to call it from your `onCreate` method.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     addListenerOnButton();
 }
```

Comment: To add to this, the fact that the method name is greyed out is telling you that the method is not being used.

Comment: @IvanWooll of course that is a very straightforward identifier

Comment: This answer my problem. Sorry I should have do more java before going through android.

Comment: @Peter Festejo You're not the first person to feel pleased with themselves when they've finished writing a method only to run the app and see nothing happen.

Comment: @PeterFestejo I consider it just a slip, it could happen to anyone

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: Do not forget to call your **addListenerOnButton()** method in
>   your **onCreate()**;

Try using this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, pass_word.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

pass_word.getText() returns `Editable` but Toast needs `CharSequence` value.

```
.toString()
```

returns the string value inside the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 addListenerOnButton();

}
```

write addListenerOnButton(); in onCreate() method this will call the method nd after clicking the button you will probably get the toast.